# PHP if result equals this, then replace

Tags: php

I'm calling the 'Referring site URL' in a post array...

`data34' => $lead->getReferringSiteUrl(),`

But need to replace it with a friendly name.

i.e.

If [www.a.com](http://www.a.com) replace with 'A SITE'

If [www.b.com](http://www.b.com) replace with 'B SITE'

```
$data = array(
           //response data
           'data25' => (string) $lead->getId(),
           'data26' => $lead->getCommission(),
           'data27' => $lead->getCommissionBasis(),
           'data29' => $lead->getAcceptedPingtree(),
           'data33' => $lead->getMarketingSource(),
           'data34' => $lead->getReferringSiteUrl(),
           'data35' => $lead->getGclid() ? : '',
           'data36' => date('m/d/Y g:i:00 A'),
       );
```

I know it's something like...

```
if($ReferringSiteUrl == "www.a.com") {
    return 'Site A'
}
else if($ReferringSiteUrl == "www.b.com") {
    return 'Site B'
}
else if($ReferringSiteUrl == "www.c.com") {
    return 'Site C'
}
```

But I don't know how to work that into the above array.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: The cleanest way, would be to add a method to the class which returns the appropriate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `$lead->getReferringSiteUrl()` *before* creating the `$data` array, then you can use a `switch` statement.

```
$ReferringSiteUrl = $lead->getReferringSiteUrl();
$ReferingSiteData = '';

switch ($ReferringSiteUrl) {
    case 'www.a.com':
        $ReferringSiteData = 'Site A';
        break;

    case 'www.b.com':
        $ReferingSiteData = 'Site B';
        break;

    case 'www.c.com':
        $ReferingSiteData = 'Site C';
        break;
}

$data = array(
    'data34' => $ReferingSiteDate
);
```

Alternative, you can use a closure as a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
$ReferringSiteUrl = $lead->getReferringSiteUrl();

$data = array(
    //response data
    'data25' => (string) $lead->getId(),
    'data26' => $lead->getCommission(),
    'data27' => $lead->getCommissionBasis(),
    'data29' => $lead->getAcceptedPingtree(),
    'data33' => $lead->getMarketingSource(),
    'data34' => (function() use ($ReferringSiteUrl) {
                    if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "www.a.com")
                        return 'Site A'

                    if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "www.b.com")
                        return 'Site B'

                    if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "www.c.com")
                        return 'Site C'  
                })(),
    'data35' => $lead->getGclid() ? : '',
    'data36' => date('m/d/Y g:i:00 A'),
);
```

However, since both of those options can balloon out the code if there are many sites, I would go with the option of having an array that maps URLs to Site Names, and use that instead:

```
$ReferringSiteUrl = $lead->getReferringSiteUrl();

$referralMap = [
    'www.a.com' => 'Site A',
    'www.b.com' => 'Site B',
    'www.c.com' => 'Site C'
];

$ReferringSite = $ReferringSiteUrl;
if (in_array($ReferringSiteUrl, array_keys($referralMap))) {
    $ReferringSite = $referralMap[$ReferringSiteUrl];
}

$data = array(
    'data34' => $ReferringSite
);
```

The map method has the benefit that you should be able to build this array dynamically so you don't have to modify code at all if more sites are added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, but Jacob's version is better

```
$data = array(
       //response data
       'data25' => (string) $lead->getId(),
       'data26' => $lead->getCommission(),
       'data27' => $lead->getCommissionBasis(),
       'data29' => $lead->getAcceptedPingtree(),
       'data33' => $lead->getMarketingSource(),
       'data34' => ($lead->getReferringSiteUrl() == "www.a.com")?'Site A':(($lead->getReferringSiteUrl() == "www.b.com")?'Site B':(($lead->getReferringSiteUrl() == "www.c.com")?'Site C':'')),
       'data35' => $lead->getGclid() ? : '',
       'data36' => date('m/d/Y g:i:00 A'),
   );
```

Comment: Thanks guys! There are only 5 sites and there won't be that many new ones added, so gone with the IIFE option. 

Made my day getting this boxed off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where $lead comes from, but you could just hardcode those:

```
function getReferringSiteUrl() {
    // Do whatever you had before in your getReferringSiteUrl function.
    $referringSiteURL = 'www.a.com';
    $sites = [
        'www.a.com' => 'Site A',
        'www.b.com' => 'Site B',
        'www.c.com' => 'Site C'
    ];

    return $sites[$referringSiteURL] ?? $referringSiteURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few semi colons and it's working like a dream...

```
            $ReferringSiteUrl = $lead->getReferringSiteUrl();

            $data = array(

            //response data

            'data25' => (string) $lead->getId(),
            'data26' => $lead->getCommission(),
            'data27' => $lead->getCommissionBasis(),
            'data31' => $lead->getLender(),
            'data32' => $lead->getTier(),
            'data33' => $lead->getMarketingSource(),
            'data34' => (function() use ($ReferringSiteUrl) {
                    if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "https://www.site1.co.uk")
                        return 'SITE1';

                    if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "https://site2.co.uk")
                        return 'SITE2';

                    if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "https://site3.com")
                        return 'SITE3';

                    if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "https://site4.co.uk")
                        return 'SITE4';

                    if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "https://www.site5.com")
                        return 'SITE5';
                })(),
            'data35' => $lead->getGclid() ? : '',
            'data36' => date('m/d/Y g:i:00 A'),
        );
```

Comment: @jacob Have I messed something up here?

Comment: Tired eyes :D I forgot to add semi colons....  

if ($ReferringSiteUrl == "https://site2.co.uk")
                        return 'SITE2';

All working like a dream now! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).